# How to conduct statistical analysis on two-eye data

Tags: stata, paired-data

I am new to statistics and I would appreciate some help with this analysis that I need to complete.

My dependent variable: myopia (binary- yes/no)

Since each individual contributes two eyes to the data, I understand that I have to use GEE instead of the usual regression models.

However, what do I use if I want to do some hypothesis testing- for example, what test do I do in replacement of chi square test/ t-test?

For example, if I am trying to compare if distribution of gender is different in those with myopia and those without myopia, I would use a chi-square test under normal circumstances, but if I were to include data from both eyes, how do I account for the correlation between the two eyes??

Comment: As a reference, I am using STATA!

Comment: Do you have one outcome variable per eye (i.e. two in total?), or data from both eyes are predictors and you have only one outcome binary variable?

Comment: @Luisda Thank you for taking time to answer my question! so for example, I am trying to find out if there is a difference in mean spherical equivalent between those children whose parents are myopic and those parents who are not myopic. If only the right eye data was used, I would use a t-test. But in this instance, I am trying to use data from both eyes and I would need to account for dependency, but I am unsure of the test that I should use.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do depends on exactly what you are trying to find out.

For many purposes, I think that the average vision across the two eyes would be good; for other purposes, you might want to use better eye or worse eye. And for yet other purposes, you might want to look at the difference. For any of these, the problems of dependent errors disappears.

How exactly you would use both at once is unclear to me. Why do you want to do this? If you do want to do it, then GEE is, indeed, one option. You could also uses a multilevel model. But, this seems to answer the question you ask - that is, you use GEE (or MLM) instead of a t-test or chi-square. Both GEE and MLM are available for continuous or categorical dependent variables.

I'd also be leery of classifying people into myopic and not myopic. Myopia varies. I would use a continuous measure of myopia; I believe the usual method is to use logMAR (log of the minimum angle of resolution see Oduntan et al (2009) *A Comparison of Two Methods of logMAR Visual Acuity Data Scoring for Statistical Analysis* and other papers).

Comment: Thank you for taking time off to answer my question! For example, I am trying to find out if there is a difference in the proportion of girls in those with myopic parent (defined as less than or equal to -0.5D) and those without any myopic parents. However, each girl contributes two eyes into the analysis. Do I go straight into using GEE? Because I have learnt to use chi square under such circumstances.

Comment: You have to decide how to treat the two eyes. Worse eye? Best eye? Average of the two? I think that's the vital substantive point. With any of those choices, the problem of two eyes disappears.

Comment: Hi Peter, i have been told by my prof to use both eyes to increase power...

Comment: Well, if you have to use both eyes, then I think you need GEE or MLM. But I think it will be answering the wrong question, unless your research is purely about heritability and genetics and such.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Sorry Peter, one more question! Do you have any idea how I can conduct analysis according to what is described in this article using stata?-
Chi-Square Test for R×CContingency Tables with Clustered Data
Jung et al (2003) Chi-Square Test for R×C Contingency Tables with Clustered Data

Comment: No. sorry. I don't use Stata.